Shower Stall Leak - Looking for some approaches
I realize there is not an easy "fix" for this. Just looking for some "best" approaches to how to deal with finding and fixing this so cascading work is minimized. Let me explain ...
We have a second floor shower stall with a grouted tile floor (ie no visible stall basin). From an earlier exploration behind the wall with the shower faucet, we did see a liner/water-membrane - that plumber said it looks like it was well placed with enough coverage (this was a very small view of 1 side of the entire substrate).
Recently we noticed discoloration on the external wall siding. We thought it might have either been cheap siding or potential damage just noticed from a toilet tank leak 2 years ago (toilet water line connector cracked and had a slow leak).
Been toying with how to clean the siding. This morning went outside after a shower to contemplate cleaning ideas, and noticed water drips. Dried them off, ran the shower, and sure enough saw a bead of water appear. Let it dry, ran another shower that "might" have a mutual down drain, and there appeared to be no water. This could have been happening for weeks, months, or a year at this point.
Isolated it to a leaky basin, the drain of that the shower, or the hot/cold -- so yeah, not really an isolation trying to figure this out. It could be the toilet again - its not the feeder line, need to assess when the weather passes and rain stops. Will also try pouring water down the drain to isolate that.
Took a moisture sensor to the ceiling below the shower, appears dry - although there is a cabinet exactly were the leak probably is. No visible damage on the ceiling or cabinet. However, the wall next to the cabinet does appear to have a higher moisture percent (10-15% versus 2-6%).
We know there is an issue. I dont know if its a plumber or a whole shower tile makeover ... but Im not sure where to start to call to do the initial assessment as I dont want to blast holes everywhere out of the gate.
I know there is no easy path here. Its either under the tile or above the ceiling. Just looking for ideas. Should I call the insurance at this point without knowing the extent?

Supply pipes will be a constant leak and usually in the the walls.  Drain pipe leaks will only happen when in use and mainly in the floor/ceiling and sometimes in the wall area.  Sometimes cutting into a drywall ceiling is better than digging into a tile floor.  A small hole in drywall is the same as a big hole to repair and big is usually easier to fix.

Thanks, was thinking about one of the 2 shower heads after the hot/cold valves are turned on. But, yes, not the hot/cold supply themselves.
Ive got a fiber optic scope, gonna go up the kitchen light cans. I think I was able to see the drain at one point 2 years when investigating. Appreciate the input, the drywall would be the best first course of action
